# Store selected column names in user-defined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently facing a problem with searching values from columns specified in user-defined table. I've got my .NET program in which I define which parameters are going to be searched for. I've decided that the best way to achieve this is to store this values (selected columns) in a list. Now I have to do something like that:

```
SELECT
    @MyColumnNamesInAList <- I do not know how to iterate it properly
FROM 
    xyz
```

What is more, I have to insert NULL if there is no corresponding column in `xyz`.

In C# code I would do something like this:

```
foreach(var column in MyColumnNamesInAList)
{
    if(!xyz.Contains(column)
        "NULL AS " + column.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @MyColumnNamesInAList <- I do not know how to iterate it properly

```
DECLARE @MyColumnNamesInAList VARCHAR(50) = 'ID,Name'
DECLARE @xml AS XML
SET @xml = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@MyColumnNamesInAList,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS Columns FROM @xml.nodes('X') AS T(N)
```

/*

```
Columns
--------
ID
Name
```

*/

> In C# code I would do something like this:
>
> foreach(var column in MyColumnNamesInAList)
>
> {
>
> ```
> if(!xyz.Contains(column)
>
>     "NULL AS " + column.Name;
> ```
>
> }

Consider we have a table as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTesttable]([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[Name] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

Now If we execute the below query, we can figure out the extra columns -

```
DECLARE @MyColumnNamesInAList VARCHAR(50) = 'ID,Name,NewColumn1,NewColumn2'
DECLARE @xml AS XML
SET @xml = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@MyColumnNamesInAList,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)
SELECT X.Column_Name 
FROM (SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS Column_Name FROM @xml.nodes('X') AS T(N))X 
EXCEPT 
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tblTesttable')
```

/*

```
Column_Name
-----------
NewColumn1
NewColumn2
```

*/

> What is more, I have to insert NULL if there is no corresponding
>   column in xyz.

Now here I will give you a hint (I want you to solve this part) (:

You need to issue

```
ALTER TABLE N'tblTesttable' ADD NewColumn1  VARCHAR(20) NULL
ALTER TABLE N'tblTesttable' ADD NewColumn2  VARCHAR(20) NULL
```

You need to build the query dynamically and using the previous stuffs that we shared.

Hope you understand.

All the best!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should dynamically generate the query directly in your .NET program.

You could do it with system view and the `EXEC` command but that will run poorly on SQL Server.

Watch out for SQL injection if the values you're using come from the end-user.